# How to prevent directory traversal attack from Python code

Tags: python, directory-traversal

I need to prevent from `directory traversal attack` from my code using Python. My code is below:

```
if request.GET.get('param') is not None and request.GET.get('param') != '':
    param = request.GET.get('param')
    startdir = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
    requested_path = os.path.relpath(param, startdir)
    requested_path = os.path.abspath(requested_path)
    print(requested_path)
    tfile = open(requested_path, 'rb')
    return HttpResponse(content=tfile, content_type="text/plain")
```

Here I need user is running like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/createfile/?param=../../../../../../../../etc/passwd` this it should prevent the directory traversal attack.

Comment: user should not be allowed to access or modify sudo directories. So check that path is not a sudo dir

Comment: I need to prevent also that. Can you make it like this ?

Comment: not saying that its a good solution but there are around 20 root directories so check that path does not contain any one of them like if user requests a path containing bin directory then don't allow

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose the user content is all located in

```
safe_dir = '/home/saya/server/content/'
```

Ending with `/` is important as [heinrichj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3333406/heinrichj) mentions to ensure the check below matches against a specific directory.

You need to verify the final request is in there:

```
if os.path.commonprefix((os.path.realpath(requested_path),safe_dir)) != safe_dir: 
    #Bad user!
```

If the requested path is allowed to be the `save_dir` itself, you would also need to allow entry if `os.path.realpath(requested_path)+'/' == safe_dir`.

I encourage you to make sure all stuff you want accessible by the user in one place.

Comment: You should consider adding `os.path.realpath()` to it in case there is a symlink in the safe path that points outside of it.

Comment: @satya Correct. It's usually the best practice to make sure stuff readable by the world is in the same place.

Comment: Ok,Let me to implement it and let you know.

Comment: Can I write `safe_dir=os.path.abspath(os.curdir)`, If i need to give permission to my projrct folder only.

Comment: @satya No, because you may be executing from somewhere else. If the python file is in the 'safe' directory use `safe_dir=os.path.realpath(__FILE__)` though I usually separate content from code. Also note you should use **realpath**, as zwer mentioned.

Comment: `safe_dir` is giving `/opt/lampp/htdocs/Nuclear_reactor/d50/nuclear_correct/__FILE__` like this. Is this right ?

Comment: @satya I had a typo - forgot to get the dir, and name of variable: `safe_dir=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149584/discussion-between-satya-and-kabanus).

Comment: This doesn't seem watertight, because `commonprefix` just looks for the longest *string* prefix. If you allow access to `/web`, this will also allow traversal to `/web2`, for example.

Comment: And years afterwards, a security flaw is found. @heinrichj thanks! added a fix.

Comment: @kabanus no problem. You might consider using `startswith` instead, which *does* look at full path components.

Comment: @heinrichj I am unfamiliar with that, except as a string function (which acts like `commonprefix`). I do not think it's from a standard library. I'll add it to the answer if you tell me where to find it.

Answer (score 10):

you could try the methods of [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.relative_to)

```
Path(root_dir).joinpath(param).resolve().relative_to(root_dir.resolve())
```

should return the relative path starting from the `root_dir`, or raise an `ValueError` if a directory traversal attack is tried

## testing

```
param = 'test_file'
Path(root_dir).joinpath(param).relative_to(root_dir)
```

> WindowsPath('test_file')

```
param = 'test_file/nested'
Path(root_dir).joinpath(param).relative_to(root_dir)
```

> WindowsPath('test_file/nested')

```
param = 'non_existing/../../data'
Path(root_dir).joinpath(param).resolve().relative_to(root_dir.resolve())
```

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-26-a74379fe1817> in <module>()
> ....
> ValueError: 'C:\\python_scripts\\PyCharmProjects\\data' does not start with 'C:\\python_scripts\\PyCharmProjects\\testproject'
> ```

```
param = 'non_existing/../nested'
Path(root_dir).joinpath(param).resolve().relative_to(root_dir.resolve())
```

> WindowsPath('nested')

Answer (score -2):

a check like below will also prevent traversal.

```
if '..' in pathParam:
    abort(ERRORCODE)
```

Comment: This is easily circumventable, see https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal